# Show entries by a certain category AND certain lightswitch

Tags: entries, categories, lightswitch

Just thinking of an easy way for the user to manage products on a site.

Therefore is it possible to display entries by a category and a lightswitch toggle?

IE. Category selected is Photocopiers and Lightswitch is color?

Then check for those and display the entries? Stuck on the syntax:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('copier') %}
{% set colortype = craft.entries().section('products').color(true).all() %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(category).find() 

*Stuck on the syntax here to add to the query the lightswitch field*

 %}




    {# If there are any entries, loop through them #}
    {% if entries | length %}

        {# For each entry we find, do this #}
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

TIA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the lightswitch filter to the entries query like so:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug('copier') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries()
                      .section('products')
                      .relatedTo(category)
                      .color(true)
                      .all() %}

{# If there are any entries, loop through them #}
{% if entries | length %}

    {# For each entry we find, do this #}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help.